# Can Algonquin Park (in Northeastern Ontario) be explored by vehicle?

Tags: automobiles, off-road, ontario, algonquin-park

My grandparents ask whether Algonquin Park (in [Northeastern Ontario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeastern_Ontario)) satisfies the criteria in [this broader post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55493/13759).

Answer (score 2):

In general, no, there is no off-roading allowed in Algonquin Park, although there are mountain bike trails. The paved roads are the standard allowable routes by vehicle into the park. Beyond this you have to either backpack or canoe. No float planes or dirt bikes are allowed either.

Comment: Thank you. Are you certain that floatplanes are prohibited? This amateur Youtube video depicts one in Algonquin Park: https://youtu.be/RWEcLsjyioY. Also, besides Highway 60, to which `paved roads` do you refer?