# Contain the Georgian Triangle and Southwestern Ontario any 'drive-through' parks or wildlife areas?

Tags: canada, road-trips, nature-and-wildlife, ontario, off-road

'Southwestern Ontario' means [Wikipedia`s definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwestern_Ontario), as depicted in the reddened area of  Wikipedia's map below: it includes the [Georgian Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_Triangle), but excludes the [Niagara  isthmus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niagara_Peninsula) and  [Golden Horseshoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Horseshoe).

[image]

Question: Does Southwestern Ontario contain any parks or wildlife areas that contain roads or trails through which you can drive in a car to explore? [My other question contextualises](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55493/13759).

Comment: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3409/13759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has answered, here's a tentative answer:

**Not really.**

There are three main national parks in the Georgian Triangle:

- [Bruce Peninsula](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/on/bruce/visit.aspx)
- [Point Pelee](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/on/pelee/visit.aspx)
- [Georgian Bay Islands](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/on/georg/visit.aspx)

None of which seem to have any roads you can drive through to explore. This seems mostly due to their small size. I could not find any mention of wildlife areas, but perhaps someone from the area will correct me.

Comment: don't restrict yourself to national parks. There are hardly any compared to provincial parks and they don't serve the same purpose

Comment: @KateGregory, as I mentioned, I'm not from the area so I can't really tell which provincial parks would be acceptable. National parks are a bit easier as (IMO) their websites are clearer and provide more information, hense why I only mentioned those.