# Besides Portage and Opeongo Stores, where can a layperson rent watercraft in Algonquin Park?

Tags: ontario, riverboats, algonquin-park

On 2015 October 20, for three nights (and 4 days), my uncle will drive  to see autumn foliage in Algonquin Park with my grandparents, but will lodge in Huntsville, Ontario. Important assumptions:

1. Google revealed to them [The Portage Store](https://portagestore.com/contact/contact-us/) (on Canoe Lake) and [Algonquin Outfitters' Opeongo](http://www.opeongooutfitters.com/rates.htm) branch, but these have already closed.
2. My uncle's small car cannot transport any watercraft.
3. My grandparents' debilities (as described [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55493/13759)) mean that my uncle will be performing all physical work, such as all driving and boating.
4. Though they can all swim and vow to wear life-jackets, they lack any boating experience or license and so will avoid canoes or kayaks which can endanger amateurs. Instead, they plan to rent paddle boats or simple rowboats, which (they trust) are safer?
5. They intend to spend three days exploring on water, but they desire to explore a new part of the park each day. So do they only need to vary the access points? Is there a map listing all access points that offer rentals?

Comment: Where did they end up renting the watercraft?

Comment: the "rowboats and paddle boats" decision, which really doesn't seem to be based on facts, is going to make this somewhere between difficult and impossible in high summer. In October, forget it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to get an answer to this question by e-mailing The Friends of Algonquin Park as mention in the comments by pnuts.

The answer I got was that the outfitting services that are in or ner the park usually all close by the Monday of thanksgiving weekend. Which this year is the 10th of October.

Moreover they also replied that the majority of stores only rent canoes and kayaks. So it would be hard to get boats as asked in the original question.

The e-mail in question:

> Hi Johan,
>
> The outfitting services that are in or near Algonquin that would rent boats
> usually close on the Monday of the  Thanksgiving weekend.
>
> The majority of them only rent canoes and kayaks.
>
> Reina
>
> Algonquin Park Information