# Besides Portage and Opeongo Stores, where can a layperson rent bicycles, in Algonquin Park?

Tags: bicycles, ontario, algonquin-park

Beware that this question asks about bicycle rentals, while [this original](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57540/13759) watercraft.
Important assumptions:

1. Google revealed to them [The Portage Store](https://portagestore.com/contact/contact-us/) (on Canoe Lake) and [Algonquin Outfitters' Opeongo](http://www.opeongooutfitters.com/rates.htm) branch, but these have already closed.
2. My uncle has biked, but is not an expert mountain biker.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Thank you for your answer which I can accept; I thought to leave it open to invite further answers.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis You are welcome, but it is I who must thank you for the helpful answer!

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis My pleasure! If you wish help for anything else, please just message me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to rent a bike from [The Lake of Two Rivers Store](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/park_lodges_outfitters/two-rivers-store.php).

The operating dates:

> May to mid-October (7 days a week), 7:00am to 9:00pm 
>   ◦ except August 25, 2015, open 7:00am to 5:30pm