# Except Algonquin Park, which provincial parks in Ontario are penetrated by roads open to the public?

Tags: ontario

In Algonquin Park, my uncle discovered roads open to the public that penetrate the park for access to the innermost [camping locations](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/camping/drive-to-camping-in-algonquin-park.php) and  access points (ie: Achray Road, which originates from Barron Canyon Road, and then passes [Achray](http://www.algonquinpark.on.ca/visit/camping/birchcliffe-ranger-cabin.php), Algonquin Observatory and then Lake Traverse). Such inner roads befitted, benefitted, and satisfied my grandparents [who cannot hike](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55493/13759).

Except Algonquin, which other provincial parks in Ontario (please include the non-operating ones) contain such inner roads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vast majority of Ontario Provincial Parks are road-oriented. The campsites are clustered together on a little group of roads near the lake/river/beach around which the park is sited. This map of [Sandbanks](https://www.ontarioparks.com/park/sandbanks) is typical:

[image: park map]

The parks with backcountry are the exception: Algonquin, Killarney, and Quetico are the big ones, but you can find others on the [parks website](https://www.ontarioparks.com/park-locator#things) if you expand Things to Do and check Backcountry camping. I count 24 of them in all. (Non operating parks add about a hundred hits and are not a useful avenue of investigation.)

If you're looking for a park with roads right up to the campsites - **that's the norm!** Pick a park that's in an area that seems handy to you (probably using the website link above and zooming on a particular area of the province) then check out the entry for that site (like the Sandbanks link above.) Each park has a link to an online map for it that will show you the park roads.

Algonquin is not a typical provincial park. Don't assume the others are like it.

Comment: +1. Thank you as always. I had intended to refer to parks in the backcountry in fact, because my grandparents hope to experience the wild but their debilities force them within the car. Does this sentence change your answer?

Comment: those parks have a backcountry part, but for the most part they also have a frontcountry, and that is what the roads go to. (That's the point about backcountry - no roads.) What you drove to in Algonquin wasn't backcountry. Don't expect to drive into the heart of Quetico or Algonquin, The other parks are generally too small to get far from a road (except perhaps Kawartha Highlands which ironically I haven't been to and don't know much about.)