# Has O'Donnell Point Provincial Nature Reserve any safe trails or interior roads for cars?

Tags: ontario, georgian-bay

My grandparents (of age 77 and 75) are interested in visiting [O'Donnell Point Provincial Nature Reserve](https://www.ontarioparks.com/park/odonnellpoint) (a NON-operating park)  by car, but [their ill health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55493/13759) limits them to safe, constructed trails and precludes them from hiking in the wild.

[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@45.0827476,-80.0359123,12.29z) reveals that the Reserve can be entered from the east by car, but do not exhibit any interior trails for walking or roads for cars. Has anyone visited this Reserve?

Comment: Given that that site says "recreational day-use for walking and nature appreciation is discouraged due to the sensitivity of the reserve’s natural values", wouldn't it be surprising if there were constructed trails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the very site you linked](https://www.ontarioparks.com/park/odonnellpoint/activities):

> This is a non-operating park. There are no activities or facilities at this park.

If you look at other parks on the site, you will see that if there were any hiking trails, they would be listed under "activities".

It seems clear that there are no trails.

Comment: non-operating park doesn't mean it has no trails, just no facilities (e.g. picnic areas, washrooms, etc)

Answer (score 3):

O'Donnell Point has no trails or axcess by car only way there is boat.
Very rough terrain only place to hike is shore line and that' stuff.

Comment: And, importantly, "recreational day-use for walking and nature appreciation is discouraged due to the sensitivity of the reserve’s natural values."